# Is flashing a new ROM enough after phone was stolen?

Tags: lost-phone

A friend of mine had his Samsung Galaxy S 2 stolen and returned some 20 minutes later after he talked to the pickpocket and tried to play her guilty consciousness.

USB debugging was active when I checked with the old ROM, so I assume that everything was possible. The bootloaded was already unlocked, but the phone was not rooted, as far as I can tell.

I flashed Clockwork Mod Recovery and then Cyanogen Mod onto the phone, and formatted the external SD card with `mkfs.vfat` on Linux. Is that enough to get any malware off the phone?

Comment: What did you mean *"he tried to conjure up the good in one of the pickpockets"*?

Comment: I am not sure how to word this in English properly. He said that he talked to her about it being really bad manners to steal the phone (and attempt to steal the wallet) of someone on vacation. So he played on her guilty consciousness. I think that is a better way of saying it.

Comment: Fair enough, but getting malware on device after 20 minutes timeframe of disappearance, in what you did, seems bit overkill,  a factory reset would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more than enough. Flashing your ROM again should be more than sufficient. This not only allows fresh installations of any old apps to prevent spyware, but also dormant any other app data from existing apps to be largely overwritten or deemed as corpses. You can also perform a cleanup using [SD Maid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm) just to be sure.